# Error getting my website on some browsers

Tags: wordpress, firefox, web, hosting

Well i have this website made with wordpress hosted on hostgator in a web hosting. Sometimes when i access it with some browsers like firefox it give my this error:
[image]

The text is in spanish but it basicly says:

> "The conection is not safe The owner of www.domain.com has configured
>   this website incorrectly. To protect your information againts thefts,
>   Firefox has not connected to this site"

Sorry for my english.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various reasons for this error. As a primary investigation, you may check below:

- Make sure that you have valid CA bundle installed along with certificate.
- If you have URL(s) set in your code (any web page), make sure that you have used "HTTPS://" instead of "HTTP://". Because, if there is a URL in your code which is set with HTTP, browser will detect that page as non-secured and it will not load the page and will show security error.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-does-your-connection-is-not-secure-mean

> When Firefox connects to a secure website (the URL begins with "https://"), it must verify that the certificate presented by the website is valid and that the encryption is strong enough to adequately protect your privacy. If the certificate cannot be validated or if the encryption is not strong enough, Firefox will stop the connection to the website and instead show an error page

Comment: I already read this article but it doesnt give me any information on how to solve this on my web hosting (host gator). Is there any link that could help me?

Comment: If you click on "Advanced" button, you''ll get the exact error code. Based on an error code, you can get it fixed. Here's the more information... https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-does-your-connection-is-not-secure-mean.....this error occurs when an SSL certificate is self-signed, expired or when SSL cert is not meant for your website. You can contact your SSL provider for this as they are in better position to help you.